# Ampere's law - 2 current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was working on Ampere law questions and starting thinking.

If the attractive force of two parallel current carrying wires was strong enough, could the two wires actually touch? Or do they need to be some distance apart in order to generate the magnetic field?

Comment: Yes they can. A problem asks about it here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/when-will-two-current-carrying-wires-touch-each-other.907892/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in principle to prevent them from touching, but if they do it would likely create a short circuit.

Indeed this used to happen in earlier times when generating magnetic fields inside coils using large currents: the currents in neighboring turns of the coil would attract the wires and produce a “crushing” force that would eventually physically wear out the cladding around the wires through friction, with explosive effects.  Regrettably I could not find an example of such an explosion on YouTube or similar sites but depending on the size of the coils the result could be quite dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed happens and is a well-known and quite universal phenomenon in magnets and plasmas.

'A pinch is the compression of an electrically conducting filament by magnetic forces, or a device that does such. The conductor is usually a plasma, but could also be a solid or liquid metal. Pinches were the first type of device used for experiments in controlled nuclear fusion power. ... Pinches occur naturally in electrical discharges such as lightning bolts, planetary auroras, current sheets, and solar flares.'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)